# dplyr: summarise, object not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder why I can not find an object created with `dplyr`, example:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
    summarise(max1 = max(cyl))
```

8

```
max1
```

> Error: object 'max1' not found

neither is  here:

```
names(mtcars)

[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" .
[11] "carb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

- you didn't save your modification of `mtcars` (either to a new variable or overwriting `mtcars`)
- `max1` is a variable *within* a data frame/tibble

e.g.

```r
mm <- mtcars %>% summarise(max1=max(cyl))
mm$max1
[1] 8
```

If you want a standalone variable that holds the max value of `cyl`:

```r
max1 <- max(mtcars$cyl)
```